# Playing Blobs in html5 audio causing interruptions

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I have two audio players on my page. I want to download mp3 and play as blobs. When I'm loading first blob to first player everything is ok. When second mp3 is downloaded and loaded to second player as blob - sound from first player disappears, but timeupdate event is fired. This happens only on ios browsers. Desktop and android is good. Using axios to download tracks.

```
  axios
    .get("https://example.com/track.mp3", {
      responseType: 'blob',
    })
    .then((track) => {
      window.audioEngine.player1.loadAudioFile(
        URL.createObjectURL(track.data)
      );
    });
```

And simple function to load track

```
async loadAudioFile(track: string, startTime = 0) {
    this.player.src = track;
    await this.player.play();
}
```

Comment: I would suggest using `AudioWorkletNode`.